# Tracking default events in Firebase Analytics for Web

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-analytics

I am creating a web application using React and I just integrated the new [Google Analytics for Firebase Web.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web)

I have managed to capture a few test events successfully, but now I want to track where the users coming from.

To do this, I am thinking of adding query string params to my url, like: `https://my-app.com?source=qr_code`, and adding an event to Google Analytics with the `source` property. However I would also like to have all events share this `source` property, but I didn't found how add a default event parameter to all events. Is this possible?

Currently I am just doing this: `analytics.logEvent('app_open', { source });`

Also it seems that Firebase Dynamic Links use the following query string params to track their source: `utm_source`, `utm_medium` and `utm_campaign`. I tried to add them to my URL in the hopes that Google Analytics would process them automatically, but this didn't seem to happen. Is there a way to use those params automatically?